# Select and sums from another table. Whats wrong with this SQL?

Tags: sql

Whats wrong with this SQL?

```
SELECT Id, (select SUM(VALUE) from SomeTable) AS SumValue, GETDATE()
FROM MyTable
WHERE SumValue > 0
```

Comment: Take a look at SQL's HAVING rather than WHERE

Comment: `TABLE` is a reserved work in SQL and can't be used as a table name without quoting.

Comment: What error message are you getting or is it just returning the wrong results? In which, case a more detailed example is needed to answer the question.

Comment: What DMBS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use aliased columns in the SELECT clause in the same query, except in ORDER BY.

It needs to be subqueried

```
SELECT Id, SumValue, GETDATE()
FROM (
    SELECT Id, (select SUM(VALUE) from TABLE) AS SumValue
    FROM MyTable
) X
WHERE SumValue > 0
```

That is the general case.  For your specific query, it doesn't make sense because the subquery is not correlated to the outer query, so either NO rows show, or ALL rows show (with the same SumValue).  I will simply assume you have simplified the query a lot since a table name of "table" doesn't really work.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably rewrite like this:

```
SELECT a.Id,  b.SumValue, GETDATE() as [now]
FROM MyTable a
Join 
(
select id, SUM(VALUE) as [SumValue]
from [TABLE]
Group by id
)b on a.Id = b.Id
WHERE b.SumValue > 0
```

This is assuming that the value you are totalling relates to the ID in your table?

Comment: I'd say that this is probably closest to what Chris is trying to achieve but with so little info, and a sql statement that doesn't seem to have any purpose, there can be no telling for sure.

Comment: @anothershrubery - Completely agree, its hard to try and pick the best option when you have don't have the info. Schema, possible data, expected output etc. But that's what makes it fun - right? :)

Answer (score 0):

right way is

```
SELECT Id, (select SUM(VALUE) from TABLE) AS SumValue, GETDATE()
FROM MyTable
WHERE (select SUM(VALUE) from TABLE) > 0
```